# Heroku Python deployment with two .py files using only one dyno

Tags: python, heroku

What is the easiest way to deploy a python app with only two .py files but keep it in one dyno? My files are `friend.py` and `foe.py` and my Procfile looks like this:

```
worker: python friend.py
worker: python foe.py
```

But when deployed to Heroku, the only dyno I have is foe.py. I've read other similar questions but they seem to complicated and I don't yet understand the inner workings of a python web application.

Comment: Explain what your *.py files are meant to do and how they interconnect

Comment: @Fabian They are just two functions using reddit's PRAW, doing different stuff each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are distinct processes working in parallel, the most direct path is two dynos, using different names (actually, `friend` and `foe` would work fine as process names) in the `Procfile`. Right now, you are using the name `worker` twice, so `foe.py` shows up because it's the last one defined. Two things to keep in mind -

- The names in `Procfile` can be arbitrary; as far as I know, the only "special" name is `web`, which tells Heroku to expect that process to bind to a port and accept HTTP traffic from the routing mesh. `worker` isn't special; it's just a convention people tend to use for "something running other than the web dyno"
- A dyno is closer to a Docker container than a virtual machine, so the general best practice is one kind of process per container.

If you really need only one dyno (cost?), you could write a third script whose sole job is to spawn `friend.py` and `foe.py` as subprocesses. In that case, everything comes up and down as a unit; you can't manage friend and foe independently.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep it free. So should I use something like `subprocess.Popen` to start both those files?

Comment: That will work, though I'd personally start with `multiprocessing`. Your script would do something like `import friend`, then call `multiprocessing.Processing(target=friend.your_entry_point)`. Though, if you have a database connection, make sure it's not opened by the launcher process - you shouldn't share the connection w/ subprocesses.